# trouble with variable values

Tags: jquery, variables, load

I have a set of divs that get their heights through the height of the contents they contain.  The reason I did this was because I want to switch the content inside of these divs but want them to adjust their heights accordingly, this also has to do with their heights being adjusted during an animation.  The problem is when I load the new content in the heights don't adjust properly.  I'm loading text and am doing it with jquery .load and using spans to contain the text in the external page it's held it, if I contain the text with a

for some reason it looses formating on the .load, not sure why.  I need help having the containers fit the content with the .load changes.

http://klossal.com/brigham_about2.html  that's the page, the top animation is the one using the .load and not adjust the heights properly, you can see it when you start the animation.  The second animation is using inline content adn the containers adjust the way they're suppose to.

```
$("#outpt_main_open").click(function() {
$('#header_img_outpt_main').load('/brigham_profiles2.html     
#header_karlene_salguero_photo');
$('#header_paragraph_outpt_main').load('/brigham_profiles2.html      
#header_txt_karlene_salguero');
$('#bio_txt_outpt_main').load('/brigham_profiles2.html #bio_txt_karelene_salguero');
$('#edu_txt_outpt_main').load('/brigham_profiles2.html #edu_txt_karelene_salguero');
$('#contact_txt_outpt_main').load('/brigham_profiles2.html  
#contact_txt_karelene_salguero');
profile_outpt_main_open_animation();

});
```

that's the button that prompts the load.  Do I need to have the load happen first and then prompt the animation function?  Or do I need to have the variables somehow resample with the new load content, or do they do this on their own?  Or is this something completely different?Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the animation function `profile_outpt_main_open_animation()` is using the original height of the elements, not the new height after loading the new content. To fix this, use the `.height()` function when you are calculating the top of each element.

So, for example, instead of

```
$("#profile_outpt_main_BIO").delay(330).animate({
    top:  profile_outpt_main_HEADER_ht + 20
}, 400);
```

instead use the new height:

```
$("#profile_outpt_main_BIO").delay(330).animate({
    top:  $("#profile_outpt_main_HEADER").height() + 20
}, 400);
```

You will obviously have to change all the references to the original heights in this function, not just the one demonstrated here.